# Data on navbar only appears after refreshing

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

Im using vuex for my logIn, but it isnt loading after the callback, and i need to refresh the page

My App.vue

```
axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + '/api/', config).then((res) => {
    this.$cookies.set('user', res.data);
    Vue.set(this.$store.state, 'user', res.data)
}).catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) console.log(error.response.data);
});
```

My store.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {
      id,
      avatar,
      name,
      tag,
      discriminator,
      email
    },
  }
})
```

My index.vue

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Navbar',
    computed: {
        user () {
            return this.$store.state.user;
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

my front end

```
<NavItem v-if="user.id" href="/dashboard" class="rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-700 duration-500 transition-all">
<span class="mr-3">{{user.name}}</span>
<img class="rounded-full" width="32" :src="'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/' + user.id + '/' + user.avatar + '.png'"/>
</NavItem>
<NavItem v-else href="/login" icon="login" :hover="true">Login</NavItem>
```

Expected:

1. Before login: Login button;
2. After login: My username.

What happens:

1. Before login: Login button;
2. After login: Login button;
3. After refresh: My username.

Comment: we need to see your html in view

Comment: ```<NavItem v-if="user.id" href="/dashboard" class="rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-700 duration-500 transition-all"> 
          <span class="mr-3">{{user.name}}</span>
          <img 
            class="rounded-full"
            width="32"
            :src="'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/' + user.id + '/' + user.avatar + '.png'"
          />
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem v-else href="/login" icon="login" :hover="true">Login</NavItem>```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77165744/edit) your question and add new a new formatted code block.  It is very hard to read code in a comment.

Comment: just edited my post